# Why is it that a stationary bike will fall but a moving one won't?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, centrifugal-force, stability

No matter how much I think about this I can't come up with a reason to me there is no difference In the forces acting against the tilting of the bike in both the cases as mothion is in the perpendicular direction (forward) so why is it that bikers don't fall off?